# How to append data from JavaScript file to the html file dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select

I have to build JS multi select questionnaire.

In order to read the json details I use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
        var anserFor1st = json.questions[0].answers;
        var anserFor2nd = json.questions[1].answers;//If it's more than two use a loop
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(anserFor1st) + "<br/>" + JSON.stringify(anserFor2nd);
        var aString = "";
        Object.keys(anserFor1st).forEach(function (k) {aString += anserFor1st[k] + "<br/>";});
        Object.keys(anserFor2nd).forEach(function (k) {aString += anserFor2nd[k] + "<br/>";});
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = aString;
    });
});
```

I have to shoe all of the questions&answers in the same page but every time with different content (aka  question&answer). I have to move between questions by back and forward buttons. How do I display the values of the different question dynamically in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the questions in a list, as it appears you do, the jQuery to dynamically change the question content is pretty trivial. We can create a function, and pass parameters to the function telling it to move forwards or backwards in the array of questions, as long as it doesn't extend outside the array. An example of this is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnFish/rmwk7dk3/).

```
var testArray = ["first q", "second q", "third q", "fourth q"];
var questionIndex = 0;

function updateQuestion(direction) {
    questionIndex += direction;
    if (questionIndex < testArray.length && questionIndex >= 0) {
        $(".question").html(testArray[questionIndex]);
    } else {
        questionIndex -= direction;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    updateQuestion(0);
});
```

You should be able to loop through your questions and append the JSON data to a blank array in place of `testArray`.

Comment: but how the index supposed to changed according the event (clicking on the "back" and "forward" buttons?

Comment: See my example on jsfiddle. You can call `updateQuestion(-1)` for back and `updateQuestion(1);` for forward.

Comment: the problem that in my case the the content of the array is is available only after the "$(document).ready(function () "

Comment: That should not be an issue, as `updateQuestion(0)` is also called on the `$(document).ready(function ()`. Just generate the array before calling `updateQuestion(0)`.

Comment: How am I supposed to generate the array to the testArray?

Comment: Define an empty global array at the start of your script - `var testArray = new Array()`, and then make `testArray = dynamicArray` where `dynamicArray` is the array which is generated. Then, you can call the `updateQuestion()` function.

Comment: should I save all the data from the JSON in array and generate it from the "$(document).ready(function ())" to the dynamicArray which is also out of the scope of the "$(document).ready(function ())"?